# CSS Background-image not displaying on squarepace website

Tags: javascript, html, css, squarespace

so my background image won't display properly on my Squarespace website mydietgoal(dot)com/legalities

It only holds the black background color I set but nothing more. The code i've tested, when plugged into codepen works perfectly but not when i plug it into my site.

The javascript works perfectly fine on both. But in the CSS area where i plug my image links, they don't appear.

(The rest of the code is repeated for the next 2 div containers, if it could be solved with just the first that'd be great)

Thank you so much,

Chris

Codepen: i.imgur.com/M8Jwoy6.png?1
My site: mydietgoal(dot)com/legalities

```
<style>
*,
*:before,
*:after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body {
    background: #1f1f1f;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
.cont {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100vh;
    padding: 80px 70px;
}
.cont__inner {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
}
.cont__inner:hover .el__bg:after {
    opacity: 1;
}
.el {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 19.2%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #252525;
    transition: transform 0.6s 0.7s, width 0.7s, opacity 0.6s 0.7s, z-index 0s 1.3s;
    will-change: transform, width, opacity;
}
.el:not(.s--active) {
    cursor: pointer;
}
.el__overflow {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
}
.el__inner {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    transition: transform 1s;
}
.cont.s--inactive .el__inner {
    transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
}
.el__bg {
    position: relative;
    width: calc(100vw - 140px);
    height: 100%;
    transition: transform 0.6s 0.7s;
    will-change: transform;
}
.el__bg:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: -5%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 110%;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    transition: transform 1s;
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) scale(1);
}
.cont.s--inactive .el__bg:before {
    transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0) scale(1.2);
}
.el.s--active .el__bg:before {
    transition: transform 0.8s;
}
.el__bg:after {
    content: "";
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.5s;
}
.cont.s--el-active .el__bg:after {
    transition: opacity 0.5s 1.4s;
    opacity: 1 !important;
}
.el__preview-cont {
    z-index: 2;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    transition: ease-in-out 0.3s;
}
.cont.s--inactive .el__preview-cont {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(10px);
}
.cont.s--el-active .el__preview-cont {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(30px);
    transition: all 0.5s;
}
.el__heading {
    color: #ffffff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 18px;
}
.el__preview-cont:hover {
    opacity: 0;
}
.el__content {
    z-index: -1;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 30px;
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    transition: all 0.1s;
}
.el.s--active .el__content {
    z-index: 2;
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: auto;
    transition: all 0.5s 1.4s;
}
.el__text {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 40px;
    color: #fff;
}
.el__close-btn {
    z-index: -1;
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    top: 10px;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    transition: all 0s 0.45s;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.el.s--active .el__close-btn {
    z-index: 5;
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: auto;
    transition: all 0s 1.4s;
}
.el__close-btn:before,
.el__close-btn:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 8px;
    margin-top: -4px;
    background: #fff;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0s;
}
.el.s--active .el__close-btn:before,
.el.s--active .el__close-btn:after {
    opacity: 1;
}
.el__close-btn:before {
    transform: rotate(45deg) translateX(100%);
}
.el.s--active .el__close-btn:before {
    transition: all 0.3s 1.4s cubic-bezier(0.72, 0.09, 0.32, 1.57);
    transform: rotate(45deg) translateX(0);
}
.el__close-btn:after {
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translateX(100%);
}
.el.s--active .el__close-btn:after {
    transition: all 0.3s 1.55s cubic-bezier(0.72, 0.09, 0.32, 1.57);
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translateX(0);
}
.el__index {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: -80px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 250px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 4vw;
    text-color: #f57200;
    line-height: 0.85;
    font-weight: bold;
    transition: transform 0.5s, opacity 0.3s 1.4s;
    transform: translate3d(0, 1vw, 0);
}
.el:hover .el__index {
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
.cont.s--el-active .el__index {
    transition: transform 0.5s, opacity 0.3s;
    opacity: 0;
}
.el__index-front {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
.el__index-back,
.el__index-front {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
.el__index-back {
    color: #2f3840;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.25s 0.25s;
}
.el:hover .el__index-back {
    transition: opacity 0.25s;
    opacity: 0;
}
.el__index-overlay {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
    transition: transform 0.3s 0.1s;
    color: transparent;
}
.el__index-overlay:before {
    content: attr(data-index);
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    color: #f57200;
    transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
    transition: transform 0.3s 0.1s;
}
.el:hover .el__index-overlay {
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
.el:hover .el__index-overlay:before {
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
.el:nth-child(1) {
    transform: translate3d(0%, 0, 0);
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}
.cont.s--el-active .el:nth-child(1):not(.s--active) {
    transform: scale(0.5) translate3d(0%, 0, 0);
    transition: transform 0.95s, opacity 0.95s;
}
.el:nth-child(1) .el__inner {
    transition-delay: 0s;
}
.el:nth-child(1) .el__bg {
    transform: translate3d(0%, 0, 0);
}
.el:nth-child(1) .el__bg:before {
    transition-delay: 0s;
    background-image: url("https://static1.squarespace.com/static/59a7820e2994ca11766093d3/t/59d53a662278e77f4c59a518/1507146344134/background-security-my-diet-goal-privacy-policy-hd.jpg");
}
</style>
```

Comment: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null" – javascript is throwing an error..

Comment: After playing around with the code further i noticed that too, im not sure how to fix that

Comment: @ChristopherKaram where is your codepen link?

Comment: https://codepen.io/chriskaram/pen/BwJaWM

Comment: Try waiting for the DOM to be ready. Updated pen –
 https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JrMjaM